# How to do calculations on column values from DataFrames with shared row keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is what I would like to do:

- DataFrames with differing length and entries
- Make calculations on column values from DataFrames where the rows have shared keys

Would the following example code be ok or are there better and more elegant ways to achieve the same? (the calculation could be anything so kindly ignore that part in terms of code optimizing)

```
import pandas as pd

values_2021 = [['Verstappen',396],['Hamilton',388],['Bottas',226],['Perez',190],['Sainz',165]] 
values_2020 = [['Hamilton',347],['Bottas',223],['Verstappen',214],['Perez',125],['Riccardia',119],["Sainz",105],["Albon",105]] 

df_2021 = pd.DataFrame(values_2021,columns=["F1 driver","Points 2021"])
df_2020 = pd.DataFrame(values_2020,columns=["F1 driver","Points 2020"])

def calc_something(x):
    return round((x["Points 2021"] / x["Points 2020"] - 1) * 100)

df_merged = pd.merge(df_2021, df_2020, on=["F1 driver"], how="inner").assign(Something = lambda x: calc_something(x))
```

Output:

```
    F1 driver  Points 2021  Points 2020   Something
0  Verstappen          396          214        85.0
1    Hamilton          388          347        12.0
2      Bottas          226          223         1.0
3       Perez          190          125        52.0
4       Sainz          165          105        57.0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use vectorial code and `assign`:

```
df = (pd.merge(df_2021, df_2020, on=["F1 driver"], how="inner")
        .assign(Something=lambda d: ((d['Points 2021']/d['Points 2020']-1)*100).round())
      )
```

or, without pipeline:

```
df = pd.merge(df_2021, df_2020, on=["F1 driver"], how="inner")
df['Something'] = ((df['Points 2021']/df['Points 2020']-1)*100).round()
```

output:

```
    F1 driver  Points 2021  Points 2020  Something
0  Verstappen          396          214       85.0
1    Hamilton          388          347       12.0
2      Bottas          226          223        1.0
3       Perez          190          125       52.0
4       Sainz          165          105       57.0
```

Comment: Thank you for swift reply! The reason for having functions is because there will be several columns in the assign and I believe it is easier to get an overview if the calculations are kept separately. Interesting with the "without pipeline", do you know if there are performance differences? My DataFrames are approximately 100k rows each.